# Char Array returning more characters than allocated to array size

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Char Array returning more characters than allocated to array size. im using devc++ compiler.

I have tried this code it should output me five character on cout but it actually return the whole string no matter how many characters i type, all are returned. Can anyone explain this? is this an error why am i getting so many elements returning from a 5 elements long array :(

```
main(){
    char x[5];
    cout << "enter elements chars";
    cin >> x;
    cout x;
}
```

i entered the word: realtime
it should have returned me the output as "realt" but it actaully returns me same elements i input "realtime" which is 8 elements more than i defined. Please help me on this. 
*even if we consider null character it should give "real" as an output but it isnt working that way. need help

Comment: Use `std::string x;` and `x.substr(0,5)` after input.

Comment: `std::cin` does not perform bounds checking on the array (as it decays to a pointer - see version 2 in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)) - which means you are invoking *undefined behavior* by writing past the bounds of the array. In this case the array is most likely allocated on the stack, so it *could* work "properly" for a while - but a long enough text will corrupt your stack (see this [example](http://ideone.com/59CPpO))